# Change picture of Google account

Tags: google-account, account-management, profile-picture

I tried to change the picture of my Google account. I did this through Gmail. However, the picture has not yet changed. I tried the things I have read in other related questions; remove/change my own contact in the contacts section etc.
However, it still has not changed.

Does someone have a solution? Or does someone know how I can get into contact with Google help-desk about this? I have not yet found an email or number I can call to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it here: https://aboutme.google.com/u/0/#name**

**Make sure your picture is:**

- 250px × 250px
- between 10KB - 5MB

> [image]

---

**Regardless "contacting Google helpdesk":**

[image]